# redux vs this.state in react native

Tags: react-native, redux

I've worked with redux for a bit after finding the mini lecture series on [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux). I'm trying to understand the difference between redux and `this.state` and when it's appropriate to use which.

Prior to redux, I set up one global container component which carried the state for the whole app. For example, when it received data changes from websocket, it would call `this.setState` on the appropriate state item, triggering UI changes (for example a new TODO being added to the list of TODOs) to its child components. I found redux to be a good replacement for this.

However, when it came to maintaining a different kind of state - say the current state that the user is on - I found it quite difficult to use redux because I had to essentially maintain my own history of screens independently from the `Navigator`. It also becomes difficult when there are nested navigators and it becomes unclear to which state "back" should take the user.

I'm wondering what are some good rules of thumb, or situations, where it would be appropriate to use `this.state` vs redux vs not manually keeping the state at all (like using Navigator).

Comment: I guess [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46639403/3694459) gives some more information for redux state vs react state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, Redux sits above your "smart components" feeding them only the bits of global application state they are meant to handle.  I would say that generally one would always store state in their Redux store unless the state being used is literally internal the component's function and would never be of use elsewhere.

An example of this might be storing the value of a textInput field where the value isn't itself the part that interests other components, perhaps it's compiled together with other values or you only want to make it available to other components once it meets some length requirements or something.  In such a case I'd store it in my component's state prior to ultimately stashing it in the redux store.

**State storage "Rules" that I personally follow:**

1. As soon as a value is of any interest to any other part of the app, may be of value later, or will be passed to other components (smart or dumb), it **MUST** go into Redux
2. If a value is literally nonsense to the rest of your application, it **MAY** be managed internally to the component via that component's state until such time as it is subject to the above.

---

Regarding your specific issue of navigator not knowing what "back" is, why not instead implement your `route` state as an array instead?  You can further write your component-that-wraps `navigator`'s `mapStateToProps` function to only look at the last item in the `routes`.

```
mapStateToProp(state) {
    return { currentRoute: state.route && state.route[state.route.length-1] }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your experience dealing with redux, is the "current screen" state or the navigational history state something that you've kept in redux?

Comment: You can definitely keep the "currentScreen" along side the entire route stack.  They need not be mutually exclusive.  Check out [this example](https://github.com/Qwikly/react-native-router-redux/blob/master/src/reducer.js)

Comment: Wouldn't a better example of keeping state to the component be when doing animations? One component could potentially update the state 60 times per second or more depending on how it's implemented.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes Not sure why that example is "better," but it's definitely another example!

Comment: I agree. It's not necessarily better, just another example. In more Redux testing, even recording mouse movements to the Redux store doesn't have any noticeable performance impact (in the small project I used for testing).