# React-Native: when to go for redux state and react state in app?

Tags: redux, react-native

I have implemented `redux` in my application. My scenario is  when navigating from one component to another component, I'm updating the `redux` state. So when I come back to the previous component, getting the last `redux` state data.

**Expected Result:**

When I come back to previous component, need to be in same state. I don't want the recent changes data.

```
Ex:  Marie ->April, when I go back,  Marie <- April
```

**Actual Result:**

Its updating the recent changes data.

```
Ex:  Marie ->April, when I go back, April <- April
```

How could I write a app structure for this? Is it `redux` needed here? or Should I manage along with component state by passing as a `params` when navigating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm not sure if my answer is the correct way of implementation. But currently, I'm doing it like this:*

`State` of a component can be scattered through multiple locations (ex: `this.state`, class's fields, a global object or Redux).

What I understand from your question is that you are dealing with 2 requirements simultaneously:

- Part of the state of the component needs to be preserved when
  navigating back and ford.
- Another part of the state of the component needs to be shared with
  other components (stay the same) when navigating back and ford.

I am not aware of a single solution for both requirements. If I have to do it I will design the state of the component in such a way that it is distributed or scattered through different locations each serves its own purposes. Basically, I use 2 different solutions:

1. Part of the state which needs to be preserved will be put in
   `this.state`.
2. Part of the state which needs to be shared will be put in `Redux`.

For this solution to work, I do not use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), only `redux`. In `redux` there is a method called [store.getState()](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getState) which will return the single Redux state object. I make the `store` read-only-accessible globally and use it to render parts of the component that need the shared data.

Comment: This is what exactly confused in my mind. Thanks for your neat and clean explanation. Now I'm totally cleared. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I am also not sure, but i am following the above concept. We should not put all data in redux. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It’s good to know which to use when.

**Duration**

Different pieces of state are persisted for different amounts of time. I loosely categorize time into these groups:

**Short term:** data that will change rapidly in your app - *store this type of data in local React state*

**Medium term:** data that will likely persist for a while in your app - *store the state in the Redux store*

**Long term:** data that should last between multiple visits to your site - *stored somewhere else likely to a database on a server or into local storage*

check here for more info: [React State vs Redux State When and Why?](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is required in more than one class then use redux state else use react state,
it depends upon the lifecycle of the component.
As redux state is global and react state is active for only in the class within which it is defined.
According to your condition you can use redux state for the first component as you will comeback to it and you want Marie as your data and use react state for the second component as you want April as your data.